# JSON messages in SockJS-Tornado

Tags: websocket, tornado, sockjs

In `on_message()` method of SockJS-Tornado library, I want to send JSON messages to clients: sometimes to specific clients using `send()` method, and sometimes to a group of clients using `broadcast()` method.

I wonder whether I need to use something like `simplejson` to encode string-keyed dictionary object myself before sending the message, i.e.

```
on_message(self, message):
    ...
    data = {'type': 1, 'body': 'blah'}
    msg = json.dump(data)
    # self.send(msg) or self.broadcast(conns, msg)
```

Or the encoding part is already taken care of by SockJS-Tornado? In addition, is it true that `message` argument in `on_message()` method is always also a JSON object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SockJS is websocket emulation layer. Websockets don't support anything except of text and binary data.

So, while you can send arbitrary python object over the wire (sockjs-tornado will do internal json serialization and does not enforce strings), this is discouraged for compatibility reasons.

Yes, double encoding will happen if json is used as a application protocol. However, if you're going to have broadcast functionality - use optimized broadcast() method, it will do json-encoding only once for all recipients.

There was related discussion in mailing list as well: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sockjs/vsFvHqppq5g

Comment: so SockJS-Torando does do json encoding for each outgoing msg, in which case, i just need to do: `msg = {'type': 1, 'body': blah}` and then either `self.send(msg)` or `self.broadcast(conns, msg)`. Why would I want encode the msg into JSON twice?

Comment: Because this is "bad practice". If you're going to switch to native websockets later, you will have to fix your code to apply JSON encoding before sending anything.

Think of SockJS as websocket replacement, which can not send anything except of text. Yes, you can send arbitrary Python object over the wire, but in next SockJS version your code might break, as it is not expected behavior.

Comment: just to confirm, even for using `broadcast()` method, we still need to encode the msg once ourselves before calling it, right?

Comment: Yep, anything you send over the wire should be converted to the string.

Let me explain what broadcast() method does. Lets say you want to send one message to thousand recipients. You can loop through them and call .send() for each client object. If your application protocol is JSON, this will require encoding same message 2000 times.

However, if you will use broadcast(), same message will be encoded only two times despite number of recipients.